# Implementing non-overlapping calls to a method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, system.reactive, xunit

I'm developing a websocket client wrapper. The third-party server I'm connecting to manages sessions, and it doesn't tolerate concurrent sessions. If the `AuthenticateAsync` method is called twice in a row, both sessions get terminated since they overlap: the first one is still active for a short duration even as the second one starts.

Here's a basic representation of the `AuthenticateAsync`:

```cs
public async Task AuthenticateAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting authentication...");
    await Task.Delay(3000); // Simulating the I/O network call to the server's API
    Console.WriteLine("Authentication completed.");
}

public async Task GetAccountInformationAsync()
{
    // TODO: Check if we're logged in
}
```

I've got two ideas to fix this:

1. When `AuthenticateAsync` is called twice, the second call should be waiting for the first one to complete. This ensures that if the first call fails, the second one automatically retries. I've realized that using a `TaskCompletionSource` makes this approach fairly straightforward to implement. However, I want to do that using Rx.NET.
2. We use the state design pattern to control our login process. Our system can be in three states: LoggedOff, LoggingIn, or LoggedIn. When AuthenticateAsync is called, the system checks its current state. If it's already LoggingIn or LoggedIn, another login won't start. This stops two logins from happening at the same time.

If we call `AuthenticateAsync` 5 times in a row, we should get:

- Logon succeeded
- Already logging in (fail fast rather than waiting for the previous call to complete)
- Already logging in
- Already logging in
- Already logging in

### Snippet

This is how I implemented the 2nd idea. Please note that we don't set the state to LoggedIn right after the `logonAction` completes but after a manual call to `SetLoggedInState`/`SetLoggedOffState`, which we do once we receive response from the server.

```cs
public enum LogonState
{
    LoggedOff,
    LoggingIn,
    LoggedIn
}

public class StateTransitionResult
{
    public bool Success { get; }
    public string Message { get; }

    public StateTransitionResult(bool success, string message)
    {
        Success = success;
        Message = message;
    }

    public static StateTransitionResult Ok() => new(true, string.Empty);
    public static StateTransitionResult Fail(string message) => new(false, message);
}

public class LogonStateManager
{
    private readonly BehaviorSubject<LogonState> _loginStateSubject = new(LogonState.LoggedOff);
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _logonLock = new(1, 1); // Allows one caller at a time

    public IObservable<LogonState> CurrentLogonState => _loginStateSubject.AsObservable();

    public async Task<StateTransitionResult> TryLogonAsync(Func<Task> logonAction)
    {
        await _logonLock.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            if (!CanTransitionTo(LogonState.LoggingIn))
            {
                return StateTransitionResult.Fail(GetMessageForLogonState(_loginStateSubject.Value));
            }

            _loginStateSubject.OnNext(LogonState.LoggingIn);
            await logonAction();
            // At this point, we're still "LoggingIn". It's up to the caller to determine the final state.
            return StateTransitionResult.Ok();

        }
        finally
        {
            _logonLock.Release();
        }
    }

    public StateTransitionResult SetLoggedOffState()
    {
        if (!CanTransitionTo(LogonState.LoggedOff))
        {
            return StateTransitionResult.Fail("Cannot transition to LoggedOff from current state.");
        }

        _loginStateSubject.OnNext(LogonState.LoggedOff);
        return StateTransitionResult.Ok();

    }

    public StateTransitionResult SetLoggedInState()
    {
        if (!CanTransitionTo(LogonState.LoggedIn))
        {
            return StateTransitionResult.Fail("Cannot transition to LoggedIn from current state.");
        }

        _loginStateSubject.OnNext(LogonState.LoggedIn);
        return StateTransitionResult.Ok();

    }

    private bool CanTransitionTo(LogonState targetState)
    {
        var currentState = _loginStateSubject.Value;

        switch (currentState)
        {
            case LogonState.LoggedOff:
                return targetState == LogonState.LoggingIn;

            case LogonState.LoggingIn:
                return targetState == LogonState.LoggedIn || targetState == LogonState.LoggedOff;

            case LogonState.LoggedIn:
                return targetState == LogonState.LoggedOff;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private string GetMessageForLogonState(LogonState state) =>
        state switch
        {
            LogonState.LoggingIn => "The system is in the process of logging in.",
            LogonState.LoggedIn => "The system is already logged in.",
            LogonState.LoggedOff => "The system is currently logged off.",
            _ => "Unknown logon state."
        };
}

public class LogonStateManagerTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task DefaultLogonStateIsLoggedOff()
    {
        // Arrange
        var sut = new LogonStateManager();

        // Act
        var state = await sut.CurrentLogonState.FirstAsync();

        // Assert
        state.Should().Be(LogonState.LoggedOff);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task OnlyOneLogonCallSucceedsWhenConcurrentlyInvoked()
    {
        // Arrange
        var sut = new LogonStateManager();
        var task1 = sut.TryLogonAsync(async () => await Task.Delay(100));
        var task2 = sut.TryLogonAsync(async () => await Task.Delay(100));

        // Act
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

        // Assert
        results.Should().ContainSingle(r => r.Success).And.ContainSingle(r => !r.Success);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task LogonRemainsInLoggingInStateUntilExplicitStateChange()
    {
        // Arrange
        var sut = new LogonStateManager();

        // Act & Assert: Check initial login attempt and state after
        var firstLogonResult = await sut.TryLogonAsync(() => Task.CompletedTask);
        firstLogonResult.Success.Should().BeTrue("First login attempt should succeed");

        var intermediateState = await sut.CurrentLogonState.FirstAsync();
        intermediateState.Should().Be(LogonState.LoggingIn, "Should remain in the LoggingIn state after TryLogonAsync");

        // Act & Assert: Set logged in state and check
        var setStateResult = sut.SetLoggedInState();
        setStateResult.Success.Should().BeTrue("Setting to logged-in state should succeed");

        var loggedInState = await sut.CurrentLogonState.FirstAsync();
        loggedInState.Should().Be(LogonState.LoggedIn, "Should be in the LoggedIn state after SetLoggedInState");

        // Act & Assert: Try logging in again after being in logged in state
        var secondLogonResult = await sut.TryLogonAsync(() => Task.CompletedTask);
        secondLogonResult.Success.Should().BeFalse("Second login attempt should fail when already logged in");
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need a [mcve] for us to work with.

Comment: @Enigmativity https://pastebin.com/PBa1JeT7 Something like that. Somehow it works in that example but not in the one with real calls. But definitely there is something wrong

Comment: @Enigmativity, actually It could even be a new class which does: 1) concurrent calls to the method should be executed one at a time. Followup calls should wait for the previous ones to complete first 2) we first check if we're already logged in or if we're in the process of logging in before attempting any further actions. 3) don't logon again, if we are already logged in. I just need this covered by unit/integration tests in some way

Comment: @Enigmativity, here is what I did: https://pastebin.com/aXnQaGkA

Comment: @Enigmativity, I did some code improvements: https://pastebin.com/fRSkrt0V. However, if you run two AuthenticateAsync calls in parallel (foreach loop and Task.WhenAll), the first one will be processed just as expected, but the following ones would fail fast, which is not what I want. I want the 2nd attempt to wait for the first one to complete. The definition for completion would be a manual call to `SetLoggedOffState` or `SetLoggedInState` from outside the LogonStateManager class, i.e. after we receive a response from the websocket server.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I realized that I probably shouldn't be waiting for the first one to complete because that's what the state design pattern is. While we're processing the first one, the rest of the simultaneous calls should fast fail. https://pastebin.com/3WnpYU38 What do you think?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do here? The latest pastebin seems to function correctly.

Comment: @Enigmativity, hey, that's exactly what I wanted to do. I wonder if it looks good to you

Comment: I don't understand your last comment nor what you're trying to do. Can you please try to explain it in simple terms for me?

Comment: @Enigmativity, it's a websocket wrapper with session management on server side. If `AuthenticateAsync` is called twice, it's going to overlap the sessions and kill the connection, which is what I want to prevent. I have two ideas: 1) if two consecutive calls are made to `AuthenticateAsync`, the 2nd call should be waiting the 1st one to complete (completion = when we actually receive the response from the server), and if the first one fails, the second one should retry. 2) instead of waiting for completion and blocking the thread, use the state design pattern to reflect the current state.

Comment: @Enigmativity, the first idea is easily doable with a `TaskCompletionSource`. However, I wanted to implement both of the ideas using Rx.NET and possible without Semaphores too, but it looks like the Semaphore is must. The latest pastebin I posted is implementing the 2nd idea.

Comment: The test case should be fairly simple to accomplish. You just put a Task.Delay inside an empty AuthenticateAsync and a logger message which you make sure it's not called twice before we get a server response (or at least simulate one, by manually calling a method or something after a few seconds - e.g. `SetLoggedOffState`/`SetLoggedInState` in my code are manually called when we receive a server response depending on whether the response was successful or not).

Comment: @Enigmativity, updated the thread mate. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: Have you looked at the `EventLoopScheduler` in Rx? It can be used to schedule multiple observables (or called directly) and it ensure only one execution on a single dedicated thread.